# シェルスクリプトをコマンドラインからしか実行できないようにしたい

Tags: python, bash, sh

シェルスクリプトをコマンドラインからしか実行できないようにしたいです。

そこで思いついたのが、pythonで見たことある以下の書き方です。
(importでは実行されないようにしている）

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

シェル（bashを想定）でもこんな簡単に出来るでしょうか。
また、そもそも別の方法があればご教示頂きたいです。

特殊変数の$0と実ファイル名を比較する方法だと、実ファイル名を変更した時にスクリプト内のファイル名も修正しないといけない気がしてます。そこで上記のpythonのようなやり方が
ベストかなと思いついたところです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「コマンドラインからしか実行できないように」というのは、`chmod +x`したshebang付きスクリプトを`./foo.sh`で実行許可／`bash foo.sh`では実行禁止(？)したい、という事ですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
別のシェルスクリプトファイルからは実行できない（読み込まれない）ようにしたいという意味です。
foo.shを実行させたくないファイルとして。

`#/usr/bin/bash
 #中略
foo.sh #←こうやって実行できないようにしたい
`

スクリプトファイル内からのみ実行できないようにする事が可能かという意味合いです。

Comment: スクリプトファイルを間接的に起動する方策はいくつもあるので　 `cat foo.sh | bash` とか、そもそも「なぜ」したいのかを提示いただくと代案が出るかもしれないです。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

bashのバージョンが3以上であれば、`BASH_SOURCE`が使えると思います:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ "${0}" = "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" ] || return 0
```

冒頭に入れておけばスクリプトが`source`された時にreturnします。

---

追記: 他のスクリプトの中で実行されるパターンを潰すのであれば、親プロセスから実行コマンドを確認するのがスマートかなぁと思います。

```
#!/bin/sh
[ "`ps -o comm= $PPID`" = "-bash" ] || exit 1
```

bashの前についているハイフン`-`はログインシェルを意味します。

```
$ man bash | less '+/^[ ]*exec '
```

> If the -l option is supplied, the shell places a dash at the begin-ning of
>   the zeroth arg passed to command.  This is what login(1) does.

Comment: `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`は初めて知りました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 質問のコメント欄拝見した感じですと、`source` を抑止しても目的は果たせない感じがしますね。

Comment: `source`じゃなくて実行された場合の回避方法について追記しました。しかし実行を禁じる目的が協調的か攻撃的かで結局やることが異なりそうな予感がします。

Answer (score 4):

> 別のシェルスクリプトファイルからは実行できない（読み込まれない）ようにしたい

シェル変数[`$SHLVL`](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/flinux/rensai/linuxtips/529shelldep.html)を使えば、要望に近いことは実現できます。以下は`bar.sh`から`foo.sh`を呼び出す例です。

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/sh
if [ 2 -lt $SHLVL ]; then
  exit
fi
echo Hello,

$ cat bar.sh
#!/bin/sh
./foo.sh
echo World!

$ ./foo.sh
Hello,
$ ./bar.sh
World!
```

ただし、新しいシェルを起動せずに`bar.sh`を呼び出したり、シェルレベルが2以上の状態で`foo.sh`を呼び出すケースには対応できません。

```
$ . bar.sh
Hello,
World!

$ bash
$ echo $SHLVL
2
$ ./foo.sh
Hello,
```

Comment: 詳しく回答いただきありがとうございます。ケースバイケースでしょうが参考になりました。

Answer (score 2):

Shebang行を読んだOSにより実行された場合に、特定の環境変数を設定する方法を考えてみました。
Shebang行を以下のようにすれば起動されたインタプリタのプロセスの環境変数`"__SHEBANG__"`が "1" に設定されます。

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -e$ENV{'__SHEBANG__'}=1;exec('インタプリタ',@ARGV)
```

Shellスクリプト部では、この`"__SHEBANG__"`が `"1"`かどうかで処理を分けることが出来ます。

```sh
#!/usr/bin/perl -e$ENV{'__SHEBANG__'}=1;exec('sh',@ARGV)
# shell script (not perl)

[ "$__SHEBANG__" = "1" ] || exit 1
unset __SHEBANG__

echo 'shebang行の設定により起動されました'
```

Pythonなどでも同じように出来ます。

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -e$ENV{'__SHEBANG__'}=1;exec('python3',@ARGV)
# python3 script (not perl)

import os
import sys

if os.environ.get('__SHEBANG__', '') != '1': sys.exit(0)
del os.environ['__SHEBANG__']

print('shebang行の設定により起動されました')
```

Shebang行にPerlを使っているのは以下を満たすコマンドがPerlしか思い付かなかったからです。

1. 環境変数を設定出来る
2. 与えられた引数をそのまま渡して別プロセスを起動できる
3. 上記の処理を、空白を含まない一つの引数で指示できる
   (Shebang行の引数部分に空白があった場合、OSによって扱いが違います。
   Linuxの場合、空白を含んだ一つの引数と見なされますが、空白で区切られた複数の引数と見なすOSもあるようです。
   よってshebang行では、空白を含まない一つの引数のみ使うようにしました)

Comment: 回答マークはついてませんが、質問の問題を解決できる手法はこちらだけのようですね。

Answer (score 0):

`caller`を使って呼び出し元をチェックできます。`sh`でも動くと思います。

```
#! /bin/sh

function called_by() {
    local by
    by=$(caller 0)
    by=${by#* }
    by=${by% *}
    echo -n "$by"
}

if test "$(called_by)" = source
then
    echo "Do not source"
fi 1>&2
```

Comment: すみません。質問を勘違いしていました。